# iOS - Portrait Locked Tab Controller App Won't Allow Landscaped Movie Player

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, mpmovieplayercontroller, landscape-portrait

I have an app that is purely a Tab Bar Controller with 5 tabs (views). I want those views to be portrait only. However, the app does allow video clips to be played and uses an MPMoviePlayerViewController to do so. But I can't get the player to rotate to landscape!

I have tried the following (along with a lot of other things):
Subclassing MPMoviePlayerViewController and overriding the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method for that class.

Allowing the app to have landscape orientation, then attempt to lock the tab views to portrait (doesn't lock them, allows them to go to landscape which I don't want).

I have scoured StackOverflow and Google for days now! 
Anyone familiar with this issue and how to get the movie player to rotate???

Comment: Have you tried MPMoviePlayerController ( as opposed to MPMoviePlayerController ) ? I'm guessing you are adding player's view to your view. Since your view is part of a controller that is locked in Portrait, it is normal not to autorotate. Try with MPMoviePlayerController. If not,maybe try subclassing it and overwrite the shouldAutorotate method. Hope this helps.Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this!

Ok so there is an important method that must be overwritten in the parent view controller (in my case, the tab view's controller):

```
-(BOOL)automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers {
    return NO;//This must be NO to allow any child views to use their own orientation
}
```

And then in the MPMoviePlayerViewController I subclassed, set this for the orientation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;//This allows all orientations, set it to whatever you want
}
```

Then I present the MPMoviePlayerViewController like this from the tab view controller:

```
- (IBAction)buttonVideo:(id)sender {
    MovieViewController *vc = [[MovieViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:@"http://www.MY-VIDEO-URL.com"];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:vc];  
}
```

And WA-LA! A movie player that allows all orientations within a portrait locked, tab bar application!

Comment: `automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers ` is deprecated since iOS 6.0. `shouldAutomaticallyForwardRotationMethods` is the replacement method for this case.

Answer (score 0):

try implementing UIViewController [containment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW81).  Designate the viewController of the tab that you are showing the movie in as the parent (or container) viewController.

You will want to override shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in the subclass to only allow landscape, which it sounds like you already have done. In your parent view controller and the tabBarController you will want to make sure that they are forwarding the autorotate methods to your subclass.  You can check this by putting an NSLog in your subclasses implementation of shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Then, when you want to show the video, add a subclass of MPMoviePlayerViewController to it.

When you load your subclass of the movies player, try doing this in the parent view controller:

```
[self addChildViewController:self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController];
[self.view addSubview:self.currentViewController.view];
[self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

or if you want to animate the change you can do something like this:

```
CGRect viewFrame=self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController.view.frame;
CGFloat viewHeight=inputViewFrame.size.height;

CGRect newFrame=CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, viewFrame.size.width, viewFrame.size.height);

self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController.view.frame=newFrame;
[self addChildViewController:self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController];

CGRect offSetRect=CGRectOffset(newFrame, 0, -inputViewHeight);

[self.view addSubview:self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController.view];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{
                      self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController.view.frame=offSetRect;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
                 }];
```

Of course you will have to set the frame for the view for the subclass of the movies player view controller before you add it.

then when you want to remove it:

```
[self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController.view removeFromSuperView];
[self.subclassedMoviePlayerViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

Good luck

t

Comment: Thanks Tim! That didn't quite work for me, but pointed me in the right direction. See my below answer!